# Finding information about ancestors from Eastern Thrace who were forced to leave Turkey 1922-1923?

Tags: 19th-century, 20th-century, turkey

I would like to find out more about my maternal ancestors who lived in Eastern Thrace, possibly at Domuzdere (now known as Gumusdere) or perhaps at Buyukdere N.E, of Istanbul, Turkey, until they were forced to leave Turkey 1922-1923.

The family consisted of 6 members or more that I am not aware of, under the family name Tasakis or Anastasiadis. Family member names: Venetis (father, DoB unknown), Vassiliki (mother, DoB unknown), Alexander (son, DoB unknown), Fotini (daughter, DoB unknown), Olympia (daughter, 1911), Anastasios (son, DoB unknown). Children placed in age hierarchy, i.e. oldest to younger

After the forced evacuation, in accordance to the Lausanne Treaty (1923), the family moved possibly to Salonika port and then to Southern Peloponnese, possibly to Gythion.

I am desperately interested to find out more about the family history/background and whereabouts before they arrived in Greece from their homeland in Istanbul. For example, Venetis/Vassiliki occupation, children DoB and school attendance, about their own ancestors (parents/grandparents) and their life in general under Ottoman rule.

Can you please help me to learn more about this family? It would be really fantastic if I could finally be able to have some solid information that i could share with my own children about the life story and experiences of their paternal grandparents and great-grandparents.

Comment: As written as is, this question is too broad. You should do your research on your side, and we can help for specific points of your research where you need help.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than seeking to find multiple answers in a single question.

Comment: For example, have you found a Greek immigration record for them?

Comment: Thank you for your useful suggestions. Unfortunately haven't been able to locate any records yet. I fear that due to panic conditions at the time with so many refuges and Greek bureaucracy nothing can be found over the net, hence my approach to G&FH. I am hopeful though that a genealogy book available in a Utah library may shed some light.

Comment: I agree that the question is very broad and you'd be better off breaking things down in to multiple questions.  Also, for any question on the site, please say *how* you know the information in the question. Even if you can only say "this information is what has been passed down in the family", that still shows us where you are starting from.